# Call a static extension method on a derived generic instance

Tags: c#, .net

I have an empty `IContext` inteface:

```
public interface IContext {
}
```

I also have two derived interfaces `IBasicContext` and `ITypedContext`:

```
public interface IBasicContext : IContext {
    string Id { get; }
}

public interface ITypedContext<T> : IContext {
    T Value { get; }
}
```

I have another project with some code that processes these contexts:

```
internal static ProcessedContext Process(this IContext context) {
    if (context is IBasicContext basicContext) {
        return basicContext.Process();
    } else if (context.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ITypedContext<>))){
        // What do I do here??
    }
}

internal static ProcessedContext Process(this IBasicContext context) {
    // Do stuff here to create processed context
}

internal static ProcessedContext Process<T>(this ITypedContext<T> context) {
    // Do stuff here to create processed context
}
```

Note 1: I have already checked multiple posts. Most of them ask about casting to a base generic class, which is **NOT** what I am trying to do here.

Note 2: Context classes sit in their own project. They are merely data structures and `ProcessedContext` creation code does not belong in context project.

Note 3: `T` can be one of multiple types that I only create at runtime. Having multiple cases for each type is just daunting and ugly. The processing of `ITypedContext` does not really care about `T`. It calls another generic method.

Comment: @RyanWilson which method are we talking about?

Comment: @GianPaolo It is actually up there. It is calling the static extension method `Process`.

Comment: The Process method, since both objects implement an interface which implements a base interface

Comment: @RyanWilson That does not help. The `Process` methods return `ProcessedContext `types which are objects being created based on the content of the derived types.

Comment: Extension methods are evaluated at compile time, and use only the static type of the object, i.e. the type of the variable **declared**. They do not know or care if the object is actually a derived type.

Comment: @Ben sure. That's not the issue though. In my specific scenario, I have a derived generic interface that I want to call an extension method on. My particular issue is getting the derived generic instance in the first place to be able to call the extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help?

This creates a suitable version of the generic `ProcessGeneric<T>` method at runtime and invokes it with your runtime instance of `ITypedContext<T>`.

```
internal static ProcessedContext Process(this IContext context)
{
    if (context is IBasicContext basicContext)
    {
        return basicContext.Process();
    }
    else if (context.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ITypedContext<>)))
    {
        Type typedContextInterface = context.GetType().GetInterfaces().First(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ITypedContext<>));

        MethodInfo processGenericMethod = GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetMethod(nameof(ProcessGeneric), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(typedContextInterface.GetGenericArguments()[0]);

        return (ProcessedContext)processGenericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { context });
    }
}

internal static ProcessedContext ProcessGeneric<T>(ITypedContext<T> context)
{
    // Do stuff here to create processed context
}
```

Comment: Seems like it would. I haven't tested it yet though.
But I assume no way around reflection in this case?

Comment: I don't think so. The required method for type T might not even exist yet, but might have to be JIT compiled.

Comment: By the way, is there a reason for changing the if-condition from `IsAssignableFrom` to what you have in your answer?

Comment: I didn't have time to test it myself and I was sure that the version I wrote did work, so I thought I'd rather use that version. I'm not sure if `IsAssignableFrom` works with generic types that have undefined arguments.

Comment: Both your check and mine are failing for some reason. I am investigating.

Comment: I had to change the condition to `context.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IBasicExpressionContext<>))` which makes sense.

Comment: The `GetMethod` is returning null now though.

Comment: Makes sense to check the interfaces, because the type of the context objext is not exactly the generic interface type, but another type which implements the interface. I didn't think of that.

Comment: The retrieval of the generic argument had to be changed accordingly, too. See edit.